# Sort Rails Model Attribute by Method

Tags: ruby, sorting, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a model that uses a method to display an attribute on a view. I've managed to get them sorted, but they are not sorting the way I need them to be sorted.

[image]

I have the red quantities at the top, which I want, but I need the green and yellow quantities reversed. The order should be red, yellow then green.

Here is the method that adds the colors the column:

```
def get_quantity_text_class
  case
  when quantity_on_hand > reorder_quantity then 'text-success'
  when quantity_on_hand > p_level then 'text-warning'
  else 'text-danger'
  end
end
```

And here is the method that creates the column:

```
def quantity_on_hand
  ppkb.sum(:quantity)
end
```

Here is the sort algorithm I'm using:

```
sort_by{ |item| item.get_quantity_text_class }
```

I feel like I'm so close, but I just can't figure out how to reverse the green and yellow numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is currently sorted based on the string values `text-danger`, `text-success` and `text-warning`. To sort it the way you want, try sorting it based on numeric values:

```
sort_by do |item| 
  case item.get_quantity_text_class
     when 'text-danger'
       0
     when 'text-warning'
       1
     else
       2
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

you can define your comparator inside Item

```
class Item
  def <=>(another_item)
    txt_class   = self.get_quantity_text_class
    o_txt_class = another_item.get_quantity_text_class 

    if txt_class == o_txt_class
      # put your logic here for items with identical classes.
      # for example: 
      self.quantity_on_hand <=> another_item.quantity_on_hand
    end

    text_classes = ['text-danger', 'text-warning', 'text-success']

    txt_class_idx   = text_classes.find_index { |e| e == txt_class }
    o_txt_class_idx = text_classes.find_index { |e| e == o_txt_class }

    txt_class_idx <=> o_txt_class_idx
  end
end
```

then call `items.sort`